# $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a $C^1$ map. $Df(x_0)$ is injective . Show that $\exists B(x_0,r)$ s.t. $\|f(a)-f(b)\|\geq C\|a-b\|$ for $a,b\in B(x_0,r)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a $C^1$ map. Suppose $Df(x_0)$ is injective for a point $x_0\in U$. Show that there exists an open ball $B(x_0,r)$ centered at $x_0$ such that $\|f(a)-f(b)\|\geq C\|a-b\|$ $(C>0)$ for all $a,b\in B(x_0,r)$.

I think maybe it related to mean value inequality. However, this theorem only tells us $\|f(a)-f(b)\|\leq M\|a-b\| $. Also, I have no idea how to use the condition $Df(x_0)$ is injective. 
I only know $Df(x_0)$ injective $ \Rightarrow Df(x_0)$ invertible.

Comment: Removing your previous post on which I went to the trouble of giving you multiple comments/hints  and reposting the exact same question is NOT cool. (And you still have the same *error* of saying that an injective linear map is always invertible. I warned you why this was wrong, among other things.) No more hints from me, though.

Comment: It wasn't nice of you to remove the previous post. In addition to what Ted mentioned, there were at least 4 followers of that question.

Comment: It is *very bad practice* to delete a post where other users have addressed your question. Please, do **not** do it again. Post here are meant to help the community, not only those who post.